# Host .NET5 worker on Heroku

Tags: .net, heroku, .net-core

I made a simple dotnet worker application, basically pinging a server about once a minute.

Trying to host it on Heroku using https://github.com/jincod/dotnetcore-buildpack, it seems to be shut down very shortly after deploy. Couldn't really find anything on this problem, as my application doesn't even have an http API to receive calls so I'm not sure how to tell Heroku it's not just idling.

I added a debug message, sending a message to a slack webhook to figure out what's going on, it seems the service lives only up to 2 minutes maximum, usually less. Many times it won't even run one minute.